# Does GDrive search use Optical Character Recognition?

Tags: google-drive, evernote, ocr

Evernote can find and identify text inside images that are uploaded. It even reads handwriting.

Does GDrive do any of this?

**Note:** I'm not asking about the GDrive OCR feature that converts images with text into text documents.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. With my digital camera, I took a picture of one page of a book I'm reading. I then uploaded the JPG file to my GDrive. I immediately searched for a word found in the book. It found nothing. After 2 minutes, I tried again, and this time, GDrive found the word. (I guess it takes a few minutes for GDrive to finish OCRing images.)